# Объединить синонимичные метки [mobile-development] и [мобильная-разработка]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Объединить:

- [mobile-development](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-development) - 194 вопроса;
- [мобильная-разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) - 143 вопроса.

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как есть устойчивая тенденция использования как первой, так и второй в одном и том же смысле.

---

Также существуют подобные метки, судьба которых также под вопросом:

- [мобильные-приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) - 96 вопросов;
- [mobile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile) - 131 вопрос.

Answer (score 7):

Это мета-метки. Они бессмысленны, потому что покрывают всё от активити в андроидах до дизайна кнопок в иосе, от пуш-сервисов для виндофона до настройки прав в левых прошивках.

Все перечисленные метки должны быть вычищены из-за бесполезности и внесены в чёрный список из-за популярности.